# Emulating armv8 AArch64 in Qemu on an x86 Linux host

Tags: qemu, arm64

i am trying to emulate Ubuntu/arm64 inside the QEMU emulator.
Hence i am following the Ubuntu wiki (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM64/QEMU) but i am not able to run it.
First i installed qemu:

```
$ sudo apt-get install qemu-system-arm qemu-efi
```

then i created two pflash volumes for UEFI:

```
 $ dd if=/dev/zero of=flash0.img bs=1M count=64
 $ dd if=/usr/share/qemu-efi/QEMU_EFI.fd of=flash0.img conv=notrunc
 $ dd if=/dev/zero of=flash1.img bs=1M count=64
```

and finally:

```
  $ sudo qemu-system-aarch64 -m 1024 -cpu cortex-a57 -M virt -nographic -pflash flash0.img -pflash flash1.img -drive if=none,file=xenial-server-cloudimg-arm64-uefi1.img,id=hd0 -device virtio-blk-device,drive=hd0 -netdev type=tap,id=net0 -device virtio-net-device,netdev=net0,mac=$randmac
```

Running this command it gave me two warnings:

```
WARNING: Image format was not specified for 'flash0.img' and probing guessed raw.
     Automatically detecting the format is dangerous for raw images, write operations on block 0 will be restricted.
     Specify the 'raw' format explicitly to remove the restrictions.

WARNING: Image format was not specified for 'flash1.img' and probing guessed raw.
         Automatically detecting the format is dangerous for raw images, write operations on block 0 will be restricted.
         Specify the 'raw' format explicitly to remove the restrictions.
```

Therefore to overcame the warnings i specified the disk format as format=raw:

```
sudo qemu-system-aarch64 -m 1024 -cpu cortex-a57 -M virt -nographic -drive file=flash0.img,format=raw,if=pflash -drive file=flash1.img,format=raw,if=pflash -drive if=none,file=xenial-server-cloudimg-arm64-uefi1.img,id=hd0 -device virtio-blk-device,drive=hd0 -device virtio-net-device,netdev=net0,mac=$randmac -netdev type=tap,id=net0
```

but i got:

```
W: /etc/qemu-ifup: no bridge for guest interface found
qemu-system-aarch64: -device virtio-net-device,netdev=net0,mac=: Property 'virtio-net-device.mac' doesn't take value ''
```

What should i do ?

Note: I do not need to boot Ubuntu/arm64 necessarily, any other linux distro (e.g Debian) is ok.

Could anyone please help me ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You used a invalid parameter:

... virtio-net-device,netdev=net0,mac=$randmac ....

Need to put a valid mac address into randmac, before the command, you can put something like:

```
# Set mac address
randmac='00:de:ad:de:ad:00'
# Start VM
sudo qemu-system-aarch64 -m 1024 -cpu cortex-a57 -M virt -nographic \
       -drive file=flash0.img,format=raw,if=pflash \
       -drive file=flash1.img,format=raw,if=pflash \
       -drive if=none,file=xenial-server-cloudimg-arm64-uefi1.img,id=hd0 \
       -device virtio-blk-device,drive=hd0 \
       -device virtio-net-device,netdev=net0,mac=$randmac \
       -netdev type=tap,id=net0
```

The value for randmac is only as example, need to choose a unique value.

cheers